# Share breakpoints with other user between two IDEA instances?

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints

I am aware of the fact that IDEA does not still have a feature to export breakpoints (like Eclipse has).

Is there a way to share breakpoints between 2 IDEA instances (2 users)? Like coping some file or similar hack-solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `.idea` folder under your project in the `workspace.xml` file, and you can try copy-pasting the `<breakpoint>` xml fragments from the `<component name="DebuggerManager">` section and sharing them with your colleague.

For example:

```
  <breakpoint url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/src/com/steve/research/stuffs/TryUrl.java" line="17" class="com.steve.research.stuffs.TryUrl" package="com.steve.research.stuffs">
    <option name="ENABLED" value="true" />
    <option name="LOG_ENABLED" value="false" />
    <option name="LOG_EXPRESSION_ENABLED" value="false" />
    <option name="REMOVE_AFTER_HIT" value="false" />
    <option name="SUSPEND_POLICY" value="SuspendAll" />
    <option name="SUSPEND" value="true" />
    <option name="COUNT_FILTER_ENABLED" value="false" />
    <option name="COUNT_FILTER" value="0" />
    <option name="CONDITION_ENABLED" value="true" />
    <option name="CLASS_FILTERS_ENABLED" value="false" />
    <option name="INSTANCE_FILTERS_ENABLED" value="false" />
    <option name="CONDITION" value="&#13;&#13;JAVA" />
    <option name="LOG_MESSAGE" value="&#13;&#13;JAVA" />
  </breakpoint>
```

Naturally, your colleague will need to have the same source files available as you do, else there will certainly be errors - but given that they do, this just might work - can you try it out?